# .net framework is not installed

Tags: .net, frameworks

I have installed .net framework on my PC but many applications are not running says .net framework not installed yet the required versions is installed

Comment: Can you give more information, like the exact error message and when you recieve this?

Comment: go to Control panel >> add remove programme and check whci .net framwork you installed

Comment: error " this application recquires .net framework 3.5 SP1 or greater" i have installed the recquired version

Comment: i had even installed the .net framework software update it says "none of the products that are addressed by this software update are installed on this computer"...plz help

Answer (score 2):

Check HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP key and c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ to be sure that specific versions really installed. If you'll not find any you need, then try to re-install.

Answer (score 1):

I've found http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/ to be useful in working out which version is installed and what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall it, and reinstall it.  That has worked for me in the past.  And double-check to make sure you have 3.5 SP1, not just 3.5!

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can try .net framework fix tool at the link below...

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301085724/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx)